# Use var as key for an object (jQuery.animate specifically)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, object, jquery-animate

I know there is plenty of related questions (one almost exactly the same), with the same question and all with answers. However, I cannot get it to work.

I need to use:

`var direction = 'left';`

as the key in this animates property:

```
this.animate({
    direction: '500px',
});
```

I'm doing this because I need to detect if an element is off the left side of the screen or the right side, and then I save which side it is off of into the `direction` var, and then I want to use that direction var to manipulate the css  `left` or `right` property, depending on where the element already is...

chunk of code is below

```
    if(this.css('left') != 'auto') {
        var direction = 'left';
    } else {
        var direction = 'right';
    }

    if(action === 'enter') {
        this.addClass('bounce').addClass('positionone');

        this.animate({
            left: settings.moveTo,
        }, settings.walkSpeed, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('bounce');
            $(this).removeClass('positionone').addClass('positiontwo');
            $(this).animate({
                top: '100px',
            }, settings.sitSpeed);
        });
    }
```

This is taken from a 'plugin' I am creating, thats why its in the "this.animate" format etc.

Comment: First of all, declare `var direction` before your `if`. Otherwise, you'll only be able to access it inside the `if`'s scope.

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought that javascript only knows function scope? That would render your advice wrong

Comment: @RononDex You're [**right**](http://jsfiddle.net/gz4wZ/)

Comment: **Eeeh, disregard my earlier comment**. That wasn't true, scope's not a issue here. Herp derp, what was I thinking. -.-

Comment: @Cerbrus It's still early, grab some more coffee :P

Comment: @crush Actually it's already 16:32 here :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the object first, then use the `[]` accessor:

```
var direction = 'left',
    animationOptions = {};

animationOptions[direction] = '500px';
```

Finally, pass the object to `this.animate` method:

```
this.animate(animationOptions);
```